# Multiple Libraries and -ObjC flag

Tags: objective-c, linker

I have a three Objective-C libraries and an Objective-C application.

The application uses library A, library B and library C.
Library A uses library B.
I need to link library C to the project with the -ObjC flag.
(All libraries are static cocoa touch libraries)

But then i get the problem that I get a compiler warning for dubplicate symbols in library B.
When I leave out the -ObjC flag the -ObjC flag, library C is not used properly.

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try the -all_load linker flag.

Comment: You can't have duplicate symbols in one Library. The error must be duplicate symbols in LibraryB and Library??. Also are they your Libraries? Are they precompiled? Do you have the source?

Comment: @hooleyhoop I do have the code for library A & B, they are not precompiled and i have the source. The error says an object in library A is a duplicate symbol (this object is part of Library B)

Comment: @Bill Brasky -all_load did not work.

Comment: @Mats - It says "Duplicate symbol _SYMBOL_NAME_$ in /path/to/library1.o and /path/to/library2.o". Are you sure that it is saying the duplicate symbol is in both libraryA and libraryB?

Comment: It is in library A, but it is a dubplicated from library B.

Comment: Did you find a fix to this? I'm having a similar issue now with AWS & Kiip Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eric, I found that there is a solution to pass by it. Make sure that Library B is not Linked into Library A (the duplicate symbols). This results that in the application will link the objects from A and B. There would be a intermediate solution, where you would link A and B into library D and then include library D only once in your application. Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

> force_load

with path to library needed to be loaded with -ObjC

from linker man:

> ```
>  -force_load path_to_archive
>              Loads all members of the specified static archive library.
>              Note: -all_load forces all members of all archives to be
>              loaded.  This option allows you to target a specific archive.
> ```